# C Syntax for a 'for' loop not compiling

Tags: c

I am a beginner in the programming language of C, coming from mainly Python/MATLAB. I wanted to try and figure out what the problem with the following section of code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int PSR(int n) {
   int psr = 1;
   // psr_up = int(sqrt(double psr)));
   for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
         psr = i;
      }
   }
   return psr;
}
```

At the moment, I keep getting the following error when I attempt to compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I was looking to see if anybody could point me in the right direction, as this seems to be basic syntax, which I believe I am following the CodeAcademy suggestions for a `for` loop precisely.

EDIT:
Apparently, you need a main() function for it to compile.

```
// Project Euler Problem 266
// https://projecteuler.net/problem=266

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int PSR(int n) {
   int psr = 1;
   // psr_up = int(sqrt(double psr)));
   for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
         psr = i;
      }
   }
   return psr;
}

int main() {
   printf("%d", PSR(3102));
}
```

The problem is now it outputs `141%` whereas I expected `47`.

Comment: It's looking for a `main` function, as this is the execution entry point to a C program.

Comment: 141 does evenly divide 3102.

Comment: you need to add a line to break the loop break; after psr = i. the program is finding 47, but then the loop continues it finds 141 overwriting psr and finishing

Comment: And in your print statement you need to include a newline or it will put the prompt at the end of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to return from PSR once you find the first divisor. Second you need to add a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int PSR(int n) {
   int psr = 1;
   // psr_up = int(sqrt(double psr)));
   for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
         psr = i;
         break; // for exit of loop
         // or simply 'return i;'
      }
   }
   return psr;
}

int main() {
   printf("%d\n", PSR(3102)); // new line added after print
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)` shouldn't it start with 2? otherwise it will always return 1